# Understanding scale of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, scale

I have found that the map section shown on one viewing is not the same as shown on a second viewing.  The same designated scale produces different dimensions in the second viewing and places that are named on one viewing are not shown on the second viewing.

Why can't Google Maps be relied on to show the same information on multiple viewings?

Comment: Three words: Web Mercator projection.

Comment: "by construction, the Mercator projection is perfectly accurate, k = 1, along the equator and nowhere else" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Distortion

Comment: I don't think it's strictly a web mercator issue, because I wouldn't be surprised if it happened with any coordinate system. You may be getting different map tiles which have slightly different coordinates, warping, attributes, etc.